# How do I get rid of "phantom user" after migration?

Tags: user-account

I got a new Macbook so I used Migration Assistant to move all my content from the old Mac... my only used on the old mac was called 'user' and that is the only user I wanted to move to my new Mac.

Halfway through the migration, however, the connection ended, so I just decided I would start it over again. However the 2nd time I did not have the option to overwrite the half-baked 'user' account. Hmm. So I just asked it to bring over 'user' as 'user2' on the new machine... then I figured when it finished, I would delete the original 'user' folder and account, rename user2 to user and be done.

So it is done. But now on my new Mac, I have 2 users in Users & Groups:

user
user2

BUT only one user folder, /user, which appears to have all the content from the /user folder on the old Mac (i.e. it seems to have brought over everything okay there). No sign of a /user2 folder at all. Odd.

I guess it sort of figured out that the first user was already set up and just used it, which is fine. I want to delete user2 from Users & Groups but the Mac freezes whenever I try to do that.

**How can I delete the "phantom" user user2? I want to keep just 'user' and the main /user folder.**

Comment: Please add the output of `dscl . -read /Users/user` and `dscl . -read /Users/user2` entered in Terminal to your question. Skip (=don't include) the items AuthenticationAuthority: and any binary data (like user picture data). You may have to prepend `sudo `!

Answer (score -2):

It may seem like a bit of overkill, but I'd erase the new Mac, reinstall it's OS from scratch, then re-import the user again, properly, without interruption.